# Styles applied to custom polymer element only inside an element with layout attribute

Tags: javascript, css, polymer, web-component, custom-element

I have a custom polymer element inside body element.

If I add styles like `width : 100px` to the custom element, they are not applied.

But once I add `vertical layout` to the body element, the rules get applied.

Can somebody please explain why is this happenint, is there a workaround, or am i missing something?

Thank you.

Comment: Could you please post your elements code so we can get a more detailed look at the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you add the block attribute to your custom element?

```
<polymer-element name="test-element" block>
```

This example works once you apply block to your custom element.

```html
<script src="https://www.polymer-project.org/components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js"></script>
<link rel="import" href="https://www.polymer-project.org/components/polymer/polymer.html">

<polymer-element name="test-element" noscript block>
  <template>
    some content inside
  </template>
</polymer-element>

<style>
  test-element {
    background-color: red;
    width: 100px;
  }
</style>


<test-element></test-element>
```

Comment: I figured out that by default, custom elements have `display : inine`, that is why styles were not applied. I assume that what the  `block` attribute does is to set the `display` of a custom element to `block`, right? thanks.